# graphile worker job causing issue to plpgsql function

Tags: graphql, plpgsql, postgraphile

we using postgraphile in our project,

- there is a graphile worker job in the task folder called email.ts
- now i have a function in plpgsql with the below structure.

```
create or replace function public.function()
returns public.xyz as $$
begin
if //condition// then
  if //condition// then
    //some logic
    return xyz
  else
    //logic
    select graphile_worker.add_job('email', json_build_object('subject', subject, 'email', email));
    return null
  end if;
   return null;
 end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql strict security definer;
```

now when I hit the mutation, im getting - "message": "query has no destination for result data" error
which I remove the graphile_worker.add_job, its doesn't thow any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to change

```
select graphile_worker.add_job
```

to

```
perform graphile_worker.add_job
```

Comment: Plus some missing `;`.